# How to understand the join function in this extension of string?

Tags: swift

Using `Open Quickly` in Xcode, I found this `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where String == String>(elements: S) -> String
}
```

I would expect it to be

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where S.Element == String>(elements: S) -> String
}
```

because I think the intent should be to ensure the elements in a sequence are `String` when passed to the function `join`.

So my questions are:

1. Is the function declaration in the Xcode 6 GM correct?
2. If so, why does it make sense?

Comment: If you try that in your own code, you'll get an error. My guess would be it has something to do with how the interface you see in Open Quickly is generated

Comment: Seems this is today's question. :D See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807157/swifts-generatoroft-crazy-init