# Swift's GeneratorOf<T> crazy init

Tags: cocoa, swift

GeneratorOf creates a generic `Generator` (and `Sequence`):

```
struct GeneratorOf<T> : Generator, Sequence {
    init(_ next: () -> T?)
    init<G : Generator where T == T>(_ self_: G)
    func next() -> T?
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T>
}
```

The line I don't understand is the second init:

```
init<G : Generator where T == T>(_ self_: G)
```

Why on Earth is it necessary to state that `T == T`??

What is this `(_ self_: G)` supposed to mean??

Thanks goodness that one of Swift major advantages is a much simpler syntax than Objective C... :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Swift stdlib header auto-generator. When resolving types, they replace equivalent types in some places they shouldn't. The actual definition here is supposed to be:

```
init<G : Generator where Generator.Element == T>(_ self_: G)
```

But since `Generator.Element` is the same as `T`, the tool replaces it. Apple's been working on fixing that.

`(_ self_: G)` is standard syntax, though an admittedly unusual style that I haven't seen used elsewhere, except for in `SequenceOf`, which was probably written by the same person. I suspect it's just how the developer named the variable, rather than having some deeper meaning.

Remember, the stdlib header isn't a "normal" header. Swift doesn't have headers. Apple does a special Apple-only trick to allow one.

[Chris Lattner commented on this in the devforms.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/993199#993199)